# create variables in terraform

Tags: variables, terraform

I'm new to terraform and when looking for variables in the documentation it doesn't show exactly what I need which is rather simple.

Given something like this

```
resource "snowflake_schema" "one" {
  database = data.terraform_remote_state.databases.outputs.database_name
  name     = upper("one")
}

resource "snowflake_schema" "two" {
  database = data.terraform_remote_state.databases.outputs.database_name
  name     = upper("two")
}

resource "snowflake_schema" "three" {
  database = data.terraform_remote_state.databases.outputs.database_name
  name     = upper("three")
}
```

I'd like to create a variable database name at the top of the file and pass it to each resource like this:

```
database_name = data.terraform_remote_state.databases.outputs.database_name


resource "snowflake_schema" "one" {
  database = database_name
  name     = upper("one")
}

resource "snowflake_schema" "two" {
  database = database_name
  name     = upper("two")
}

resource "snowflake_schema" "three" {
  database = database_name
  name     = upper("three")
}
```

What's the correct syntax to do that in terraform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to assign an attribute expression output to a module scope variable without the capability to directly modify its value with inputs, then you can use [Terraform locals](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/locals.html). In this case, you would do something like:

```
locals {
  database_name = data.terraform_remote_state.databases.outputs.database_name
}
```

to initialize. Then you can reference the assigned local variable value like:

```
resource "snowflake_schema" "one" {
  database = local.database_name
  name     = upper("one")
}
```

as if it were a Map type.